# jQuery Validate, send error message to other function

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, validation

Is it possible to send the Validate error message to other function?
As an example, I have a notification function that displays a determined message and fades away after (n) seconds:

```
notify("My error message", { selector: '#form-notification' });
```

How to use that notify function with this:

```
$("#myForm").validate({
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        var options = { 
            target: '#save_form',                               
            dataType: 'json',
            beforeSubmit: showRequest,
            success: showResponse 
        }; 
        $(form).ajaxSubmit(options); 
    }
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: take at look at [invalidHandler](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#options)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `showErrors` callback to customize what happens when an error occurs. Include `defaultShowErrors()` to keep the default action.

```
$("#myForm").validate({
   showErrors: function(errorMap, errorList) {
        //custom code here

        this.defaultShowErrors();
    }
 });
```

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate